# Trying to create simple button push playback with lock out

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pygame

Newbie here. Trying to write simple code that will playback loaded audio file and "lock out" further button pushes until the file has completed paying. I'm using a GPIO input. I'm writing on a Raspberry Pi 3b+ using python in Thonny. Using my current file I can load the file, and initialize the audio and GPIO button but I cannot figure out how to lock out input of another button push. Additional button pushes trigger the audio to play again over the already playing file.

I've tried pygame event wait, and sleep functions but I cannot find clear info on how to use them.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

from gpiozero import Button, LED


btn_playaudio = Button(27)

playaudio = pygame.mixer.Sound('/home/pi/folder/folder2/audiofile.wav')

btn_playaudio.when_pressed = playaudio.play
```

I expect file to play one time until it is completed and then be ready to play it again when button is pressed.

Ultimately this program will be loaded to a headless Pi and auto-ran using rc.local so that when device is turned on it boots, loads the program and is ready for button presses. 
(basically a push-button kiosk that plays the audio when the button is pressed - it'll run 24/7)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
import pygame
import time
from gpiozero import Button


pygame.init()
btn_playaudio = Button(27)
playaudio = pygame.mixer.Sound('/home/pi/folder/folder2/audiofile.wav')


def my_player():
    global btn_playaudio # We want changes to this to occur in the global scope
    length = playaudio.get_length() # Returns the length of the sound, in seconds
    btn_playaudio.when_pressed = None # Remove the handler while the sound is playing
    playaudio.play()
    time.sleep(length)
    btn_playaudio.when_pressed = my_player # Restore the handler


btn_playaudio.when_pressed = my_player
```

The strategy is to remove the handler while the sound is playing, then add it back when it is done. I haven't actually tested it so you may need to debug it.

Comment: Thank you - I will try that today.

Comment: Hi Rob, I tried the script you provided and it does throw quite a few bugs. I unfortunately don't know how to debug it.

>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/pins/rpigpio.py", line 213, in _call_when_changed
    super(RPiGPIOPin, self)._call_when_changed()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/pins/pi.py", line 268, in _call_when_changed
    method()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/mixins.py", line 323, in _fire_events
    self._fire_activated()